# System.AddIn support issue while migrating WPF a Composite Applications to .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, mef

I have developed a composite application model in WPF by following the Fault-Tolerant architecture provided in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/january/wpf-build-fault-tolerant-composite-applications) article. The decision to choose this architecture is because of the requirement to load few other WPF application as a Plug-In inside main application. This architecture is using `System.AddIn` library and a `FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter` method to enable tabbing between the process. Now, I am migrating all of the .net framework applications to .net core. Unfortunately, `System.AddIn` library doesn't have any support in .net core. Could anyone please provide some suggestions or idea to achieve this without `System.AddIn` library. I have explored `MEF` for a while and couldn't able to success.

Comment: MEF is perfect for this scenario. Why is the problem?

Comment: I have been exploring MEF and found no option to run a part loaded in the catalog in a separate process to isolate. Also MEF can export a UserControl but fails while importing in a host application.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a similar solution to using `FrameworkElementsAdapters` on `.NET 5`.

It looks like `System.Addin` won't be ported to `.NET Core` as it would be a major rewrite.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16708